# EmberJs: 1 model, multiple views-controllers

Tags: ember.js

I'm quite new to Ember and I'm quite lost to find the better approach for my application:

Application:
Screen is splited horizontally in 2 parts:

- Left part is a form to fill Person attributes (name, lastName, email)
- Right part is a graphical view of the left form

I don't know exactly the best solution:

**Solution1:**

- Person object for the model (instance is a person object global variable for now)
- PersonFormController to manage the form and make the attributes validation
- PersonFormView to display the form
- PersonRenderedController: to manage the rendering of the form
- PersonRenderedView (only display view, no user interactions)
- The 2 controllers have a reference to the person global variable for their content property
- Use of "connect outlets" to connect the controllers/views
  router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('left', 'personForm');
  router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('right', 'personRendered');

I'm not sure of this solution because the PersonRenderedController is not very useful and oly used for the "outlet connectivity".

**Solution2:**

- Person object for the model (instance is a person object global variable for now)
- PersonFormController to manage the form and make the attributes validation
- PersonFormView to display the form
- PersonRenderedView (only display view, no user interactions)
- NO personRenderedController (no need because only display mode for this view)
- NO outlets but manually creation of the 2 views (form and rendered) in the general template

I think that solution1 is perhaps more flexible (in case rendered view needs a controller)

Can you please advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 seems better to me. Going with outlet is always a good idea. In this case you do not have to create a PersonRenderedController. You can use connectOutketin a way that suits your needs. The following paragraph is from the source and shows how to use this method with an options hash:

> */
>     connectOutlet: function(name, context) {
>       // Normalize arguments. Supported arguments:
>       //
>       // name
>       // name, context
>       // outletName, name
>       // outletName, name, context
>       // options
>       //
>       // The options hash has the following keys:
>       //
>       //   name: the name of the controller and view
>       //     to use. If this is passed, the name
>       //     determines the view and controller.
>       //   outletName: the name of the outlet to
>       //     fill in. default: 'view'
>       //   viewClass: the class of the view to instantiate
>       //   controller: the controller instance to pass
>       //     to the view
>       //   context: an object that should become the
>       //     controller's `content` and thus the
>       //     template's context.

This way you could reuse your 1 controller for the person also for your other view:

```
router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet({
   outletname: "right",
   viewClass : App.PersonRenderedView,
   controller: router.get("personFormController")
 })
```

So all i propose is using the more explicit version of connectOutlet, which gives you more control in contrast to the default approach based on name matching.